# How to prevent Qt3D window from self-updating?

Tags: qt, qt3d

I need to render lots (hundreds) of similar spheres and cylinders with different transforms. Currently this is achieved by creating hundreds of identical `QEntity` objects. The result is the app's constantly consuming 20..70% of CPU -- even when the scene is still.

Is there a default source of update events for the widget? If there is one, can I turn it off or reduce its frequency? There seems to be no other source of CPU load but the Qt3D widget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you have a look at the [enum](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qt3drender-qrendersettings.html#RenderPolicy-enum) of the `QRenderSettings` class? It seems like you can set the render policy to `OnDemand` which causes Qt to only render the scene when something changes.

Alternatively, if you don't need interaction with the scene you could have a look at my implementation of an [offline renderer](https://github.com/Sonnentierchen/Qt3D-OfflineRenderer). The underlying [`QAspectEngine`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3dcore-qaspectengine.html) starts and stops whenever you set a root entity. You could set your root entity, capture the frame and unset the root entity, causing the graphics loop to stop which would result in less CPU load I would guess.